# Android /res/values-en/strings.xml The destination file already exists

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I have an android application by Arabic language , I want to do localization of it in English language so I have create a folder in eclipse under res called values-en , already I have a folder called values (for arabic values in string.xml file) my problem when I try to create another strings.xml under values-en I get a message The destination file already exists

Comment: Are sure you created it correctly (the folder and the new strings.xml) Are you sure there are no other strings.xml in the folder? Check it maybe your IDE created it for you

Comment: Yes there is no other strings.xml in the folder

Comment: I have created the desired folders manually then  I created strings.xml file without  problem . but when I run the application on  avd I get error message :- unfortunately the launcher has stopped!